Supabase Error - Email address cannot be used as it is not authorized
I have a Supabase Edge Function that can create new users using the Admin SDK. At some point this week, it stopped working and I would get the following error:

Email address cannot be used as it is not authorized

I haven't changed anything so I'm not sure why its breaking now.
Code:
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts"
import { createClient } from "https://esm.sh/@supabase/supabase-js@2.45.3"

const corsHeaders = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'authorization, x-client-info, apikey, content-type',
}

serve(async (req) => {
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return new Response('ok', { headers: corsHeaders })
  }

  try {
    const { email, password } = await req.json()

    const supabaseClient = createClient(
      Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_URL') ?? '',
      Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY') ?? '',
      { auth: { autoRefreshToken: false, persistSession: false } }
    )

    const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.admin.createUser({
      email,
      password,
      email_confirm: true
    })

    if (error) {
      throw error
    }

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ user: data.user }), {
      headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      status: 200,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }), {
      headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      status: 400,
    })
  }
})


Turns out there was a change in the Supabase platform that now requires you to have a custom SMTP server setup for email sign ups, even if you have email confirmations turned off.
To fix it, I set up a free Resend account and added the Resend credentials under Project Settings -> Authentication -> SMTP Settings in Supabase.
This blog shows how to do this using Resend: https://resend.com/blog/how-to-configure-supabase-to-send-emails-from-your-domain
Github Discussion: https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/29370
Changelog Update (9/18/2024): https://supabase.com/changelog

So this means that if I don't setup custom SMTP I will keep receiving this error? Email address cannot be used as it is not authorized

that's absurd from the supa side. Why do i need to setup SMTP if I do not send emails for the email confirmation...

How does this work for local development though, Resend looks like they require you to verify a domain? I have no problem doing it when I'm ready moving to production, but for local development, this is problematic.

Go to:
supabase project -> Authentication -> Providers -> Email -> Confirm Email (turn this off) -> Save

I tried doing this originally but the error didn't go away

it turns off the Email povider at all. it's not what we are looking for

no !, it does not turn off the email provider
